# Fill service block based on days i.e. to fill them in sequential for 5 days

Tags: anylogic

Fill station based on day

Fill station based on the day  I am trying to get the model to do the following: I have a 5-service block with a queue. I need the model to assign a day for each service block i.e. to fill the first service block on the day1. Then to fill service block 2 on the second day, third service block on the third day, 4th service on the fourth day and 5th service block on the fifth day. Once the fifth service block completed it will start again from service block one.

I have tried to iterate between the 5 service block using the exit and enter block through the collection and the following code:

```
double minSize = min(collection, sp -> (sp.Curing_Drying1.size()));

return findFirst(collection, sp -> (sp.Curing_Drying1.size()) == minSize).enter;
```

Please see attached images for further illustration.

[queue and delay](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ufPW.png)
[Exit and enter with collection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3mvnz.png)

The current model doesn't assign each service or delay block to work in a specific day. Can any one advice on how to assign each service block to work for a day in sequence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want to send agents to `subProcess` instances for given days?

You can add an int parameter `allowedDay` to `SubProcess`. Set it to values 0-4 for each.

Then in your `exit` block, decide where to send your agents using the current model time:

```
for (SubProcess currProcess : collection) {
    if (currProcess.allowedDay == (int)time(DAY)) {
        currProcess.enter.take(agent);
    }
}
```

The trick is the `(int)time(DAY)` which converts the current model time to a day number.

Make sure to handle errors properly, obviously.